# How to check numerical values on a plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics

Suppose we have the model:

```
tmax = 2000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.0001;
\[Beta]2 = 0.006;
p = 0.9;
q = 0.8;
\[Xi]1 = 0.8;
\[Xi]2 = 0.9;
\[Epsilon] = 0.002;
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.03;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
\[Mu] = 0.01;
\[Nu] = 0.55;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Nu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] - \[Mu]*
       S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + 
      q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu])*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*J[t] - (p1 + \[Mu])*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (\[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 + p2 + \[Mu])*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (\[Alpha] + \[Mu])*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    J[0] == 20,
    A[0] == 20},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.45}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

Giving:

[image]

How would I find the value of say `I1`, `I2` etc at time 1000 for example from the graph?

**Edit:**
From the original model in the original post, we had total population converging to $55$, this was just as expected as $N$ will converge to $\frac{\nu}{\mu}$ when $t \rightarrow \infty$. However, consider the same model with different parameter values:

```
tmax = 20000;
\[Beta]1 = 0.0001;
\[Beta]2 = 0.006;
p = 0.3;
q = 0.4;
\[Xi]1 = 0.001;
\[Xi]2 = 0.003;
\[Epsilon] = 0.0002;
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.03;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
\[Mu] = 0.01;
\[Nu] = 0.55;
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Nu] - \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] - \[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] - \[Mu]*
       S[t],
    I1'[t] == 
     p*\[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + 
      q*\[Beta]2*S[t]*J[t] + \[Xi]1 *J[t] - (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu])*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) \[Beta]1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*\[Beta]2*S[t]*
       J[t] + \[Epsilon]*I1[t] + \[Xi]2*J[t] - (p1 + \[Mu])*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (\[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 + p2 + \[Mu])*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (\[Alpha] + \[Mu])*A[t] ,
    S[0] == 50,
    I1[0] == 50,
    I2[0] == 50,
    J[0] == 20,
    A[0] == 20},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", 
     "I1(t)", "I2(t)", "J(t)", "A(t)" }, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.75}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

When we do `f1[20000] + f2[20000] + f3[20000] + f4[20000] + f5[20000]` it gives us `51.3631` which is not what we want.. why is it doing this?

Comment: Right klick with the mouse in the graphics and choose: "GetCoordinates"

Comment: @DanielHuber These are not accurate.. And since there's a overlap, is there a way to type something in Mathematica like `N[S(1000)]`?

Comment: Why you do not simply write e.g.: `f1[1000]`?

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, I completely forgot about this

Comment: If you add up the right hand sides of your system to get `N'[t]`, you get `\[Nu] - (\[Alpha] + \[Mu]) A[t] - \[Mu] I1[t] - \[Mu] I2[t] - \[Mu] J[t] - \[Mu] S[t]`.  That `\[Alpha]` loss term is the leak.

Comment: @ChrisK Ah yes. I read its as $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup N(t) = \frac{\nu}{\mu} $rather than $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup N(t) \leq \frac{\nu}{\mu} $

Comment: @ChrisK thinking about this, why isn't there a small leak when $\mathcal{R}_0 <1$? Surely this should be the case when  $\mathcal{R}_0 <1$ just as it when  $\mathcal{R}_0 \geq 1$ ?

Comment: @Math Maybe because `A[t]` goes to zero in that case, so there's nothing to leak?

Comment: @ChrisK Ah yes. Thank you, Sir,

Comment: In the updated code, `system /. Equal -> Subtract /. Thread[{S, I1, I2, J, A} -> {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}] /. t -> 20000` shows the system is approaching an equilibrium.  If 51.36 is wrong, then maybe there's something wrong with one of the parameters or the equations. It seems that at an equilbrium, the total population should be `(\[Nu] - \[Alpha] A[t])/\[Mu]`.  Maybe the coefficient of `A[t]` is wrong? In the first code, `A[t]` gets close to zero, which is why the error is not apparent.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, in the later equations where `A[t]` is not zero, this is where the leakage happens. As you correctly pointed out, it is because of `(\[Nu] - \[Alpha] A[t])/\[Mu]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to specify time

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Constants

```
tmax = 2000;
β1 = 10^-4;
β2 = 6*^-3;
p = 9/10;
q = 4/5;
ξ1 = 4/5;
ξ2 = 9/10;
ϵ = 2*^-3;
p1 = 10^-2;
p2 = 3*^-2;
α = 10^-2;
μ = 10^-2;
ν = 11/20;
```

Solution

```
SIIJA = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == ν - β1*S[t]*I2[t] - β2*S[t]*J[t] - μ*S[t],
    I1'[t] == p*β1*S[t]*I2[t] + 
      q*β2*S[t]*J[t] + ξ1*J[t] - (ϵ + μ)*I1[t],
    I2'[t] == (1 - p) β1*S[t]*I2[t] + (1 - q)*β2*S[t]*
       J[t] + ϵ*I1[t] + ξ2*J[t] - (p1 + μ)*I2[t],
    J'[t] == p1*I2[t] - (ξ1 + ξ2 + p2 + μ)*J[t],
    A'[t] == p2*J[t] - (α + μ)*A[t],
    S[0] == 50, I1[0] == 50, I2[0] == 50, J[0] == 20, A[0] == 20},
   {S, I1, I2, J, A}, {t, 0, tmax}];

{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} = SIIJA;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;
```

Display

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t], f5[t]}, {t, 0, tmax},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Purple, Yellow, Orange, Red},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"},
    PlotLegends ->
     Placed[
      LineLegend[
       {"S", "I1", "I2", "J", "A"},
       LegendFunction -> Framed,
       Background -> White],
      {0.85, 0.45}],
    ImageSize -> 500,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    Prolog -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Gray, Dashed,
      InfiniteLine[{{tv, 0}, {tv, 60}}]}],
   Row[
    Riffle[
     StringForm["`` = ``", #[[1]],
        ScientificForm[#[[2]], 3]] & /@
      Transpose[{{S, I1, I2, J, A},
        {f1[tv], f2[tv], f3[tv], f4[tv], f5[tv]}}],
     "; "]]},
  ItemSize -> {35, Automatic}],
 {{tv, 1000, t}, 0, tmax, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution, can you please check my edit in the original post?